# Accessing Laravels classes from a custom php script

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have written a script that will be ran by crontab every day at midnight. The script is basically going to check for some data in a model. So this script is pretty much independent from the whole app. I need to access laravel classes such as carbon, models, DB, etc. How can i import them to use in the script?

Comment: laravel has their task sheduling, use it! (: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling

Comment: Why not take advantage of Laravel's [Artisan console](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#main-content)? You can create commands and run them via cron

Comment: i dont really need artisan commands because i do some validation before executing database commands

Comment: I'm kinda new to laravel so i didnt know about scheduling. I will definitely look into it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: But Artisan commands will have access to Models, Carbon, etc. by default; no need to import them.

Comment: You can do all sorts of validation with Artisan. I have a lot of artisan commands that run the gamut from sending large batches of emails to updating models to grabbing information from APIs and manipulating database data. It all depends on how you code it

Comment: @ericmp Yes, but the Scheduler _is_ an Artisan Command  It's called via `php artisan schedule:run` (or at least it was in the past; I haven't worked with the scheduler in newer versions of Laravel, but I believe that is still the case, albeit a bit less direct)

Comment: @TimLewis yeah (,: still like that

Comment: okay i solved it by requiring the autoloader

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by basically checking the codes in the index.php file since the whole app runs through there and saw the autoloader, then required it in the custom script that i wanted to run and it worked. I got access to all classes within the app. I put the code below.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

require_once("vendor\autoload.php");
$app = require_once("bootstrap\app.php");

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
);
```